# Worin liegt der Unterschied zwischen "drehen", "umdrehen", "zudrehen", "kehren" und "wenden" in Sinne von "to turn"?

Tags: vocabulary, comparison

Worin liegt der Unterschied zwischen "drehen", "umdrehen", "zudrehen", "kehren" und "wenden" in Sinne von "to turn"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "drehen" und "umdrehen"?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13436/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-drehen-und-umdrehen)

Comment: Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch?

Comment: Mein Wörterbuch sagt immer "to turn", deshalb wollte ich nur wissen, worin der Unterschied liegt...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**umdrehen**: *to turn around/flip/reverse*.This can refer to (1) a person ("Er drehte sich um und schaute mich an." "Goethe würde sich im Grabe umdrehen.") or (2) a thing ("Für die Zukunft gilt, dass wir jeden Euro zweimal umdrehen, bevor wir ihn ausgeben." "Ich drehe die Würstchen um, damit sie nicht anbrennen.")

**zudrehen**: (1) *to close sth. by turning* (e.g. a water tap, lid,...); the opposite, *to open sth. by turning* would be **aufdrehen** (2) when referring to a person, *to turn towards a direction* ("Er drehte mir den Rücken zu."). This is a turn at the spot, without changing position.

**kehren**: typically used when driving a car or walking: *to make a turn/to turn back into the opposite direction*. This is a turn with changing position, i.e. usually not at the spot.

**wenden**: (1) *to turn around/flip/reverse* sth (similar to "umdrehen" in its second meaning). (2) *to turn back into the oppposite direction* (particularly used when referring to cars)

**drehen**: This is a more general word which can replace some of the more specific words above, but most often is used when referring to something rotating (without stopping), e.g. a windmill, drill...